# Calculating events in time, with respect to easter

Tags: c, shell, unix, calendar

Let's say John his anniversary is exactly on easter. Johnny his anniversary is always the week after easter. And Ellen her anniversary is a week before pentecost (42 days after easter).

How can I with a shell script, calculate the day (number and day-name) and month of their birthdays. For all future years.

I know, that I can calculate the day of easter, with `ncal -e "year"`.
In C is what I did:

```
typedef struct {
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
} Date;
```

I then calculate the day of easter (with Gauss's algorithm). And return the day, month, year to a pentecost function, that takes the day+49 and decrements the day, and increments the month.

Thus:

1. In the shell, how can I convert the `ncal -e`output from "January
   1 2019" to "1 1 2019" with only the shell.
2. If i have this how
   would you start making the rules, for the story above. (For the
   birthdays)

```c
Date easter(int Y)
{
    Date date;
    int C = floor(Y/100);
    int N = Y - 19*floor(Y/19);
    int K = floor((C - 17)/25);
    int I = C - floor(C/4) - floor((C - K)/3) + 19*N + 15;
    I = I - 30*floor((I/30));
    I = I - floor(I/28)*(1 - floor(I/28)*floor(29/(I + 1))*floor((21 - N)/11));
    int J = Y + floor(Y/4) + I + 2 - C + floor(C/4);
    J = J - 7*floor(J/7);
    int L = I - J;
    int M = 3 + floor((L + 40)/44);
    int D = L + 28 - 31*floor(M/4);

    date.d = D;
    date.m = M;
    date.y = Y;
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need all those `floor` calls in `easter` when all the variables and constants are integers anyway?

Comment: That was just a quick C example. Thus not 100% ok (it works though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a function that calls `ncal -e`

```
easter() {
    local year=${1:-$(date "+%Y")}   # use this year if no arg provided
    local easter=$(ncal -e "$year")  # month day year
    date -d "$easter" "+%F"          # YYYY-mm-dd
}
```

Then

```
$ easter
2019-04-21
$ easter 2018
2018-04-01
$ easter 2020
2020-04-12
$ date -d "$(easter) - 1 week" "+%F"
2019-04-14
$ date -d "$(easter) + 1 week" "+%F"
2019-04-28
```

Use a different date format if you choose.